# watch randomly ordered videos within one mpv instance

Tags: zsh, mpv

To watch all videos with mpv in predefined sorted order one can do

```
mpv /path/to/videos/*
```

because `mpv` can accept multiple files as its argument and play them one after another.

I would like to pass to mpv those files but randomly ordered, so each time I start watching it comes up with something unexpected.

Here what I've tried so far

```
ls /path/to/videos/* | sort -R | while read file; do mpv $file; done
```

This variant does not satisfy my needs, since it starts new instance for each video and new window always gets focused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subshell to collect the randomized lines back into arguments to `mpv`. Remove debugging `echo` if trial runs look good.

```
echo mpv $(print -l /path/to/videos/* | sort -R)
```

(Also there is no need to use `ls` as that's more expensive than simply printing the results of the glob expansion linewise with `print -l`.)

Internal to ZSH, try a clever glob trick to shuffle the list:

```
echo mpv *(oe:REPLY=\$RANDOM:)
```

Comment: @tarashypka generally I aim to not have characters in filenames that complicate life in the shell.

Comment: It works well for file names without whitespaces. For another case I've tried `mpv $(printf '%q\n' /path/to/videos/* | sort -R)`, but regardless it created espace sequences, error is still the same. Is it possible to improve it or should I constantly rename the files to eliminate whitespaces etc?

Comment: Second command works as charm and looks as magic. It's definitely time to learn more about zsh. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`mpv` has an option built-in for shuffling the order of files played (`--shuffle`)

You could use `mpv --shuffle /path/to/videos/*`